# How to submit a MonoTouch app to the App Store with XCode 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, xamarin.ios, app-store-connect

Currently, I'm finishing my very first iPhone app with MonoTouch. Having successfully done ad-hoc distribution and testing, I'm now about to submit to the App Store via iTunes Connect.

After reading a [non-MonoTouch description on how to submit](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-upload-an-app-to-the-app-store-with-xcode-4/), I cannot draw a line between the MonoTouch ZIP bundle I created and the "Archives" section of Xcode Organizer to submit to iTunes Connect.

In addition, I have read the [instructions in the MonoTouch documentation](http://ios.xamarin.com/Documentation/Building_for_Distribution), they only mention the submission with the words:

> ...and submit it to Apple.

**So my question is:**

How do I manage to convert/put my MonoTouch ZIP bundle into the "Archives" section of Xcode Organizer?

**Update with solution:**

[As Emanuele Sabetta pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684812/how-to-submit-a-monotouch-app-to-the-app-store-with-xcode-4/7685254#7685254), there is still the Application Loader application. So I simply dropped the idea of using the Xcode Organizer and instead used the Application Loader.

To open Application Loader, I searched for it with Spotlight...

[image]

...and then started it...

[image]

From there on, everything worked as expected, I went through the wizard and now have an app in iTunes Connect that is pending for review.

Comment: Now I've also [asked this in the Xamarin support forum](http://support.xamarin.com/customer/portal/questions/48940-how-to-submit-a-monotouch-app-to-the-app-store-with-xcode-4-), maybe they can answer, this, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to obtain AppID and a Distribution Certificate, following this guide:

http://www.grunewalddev.com/ClientDistribution.pdf

The you can follow the official Xamarin guide to compile the binary and zipping it (edit: but as you noted it's not updated to XCode 4):

http://ios.xamarin.com/Documentation/Building_for_Distribution

You must upload the zip with the MacOSX application called "Application Loader" (it cames bundled with XCode 4).

Then you should follow the iTunesConnect guide:

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf

Comment: That's exactly the link I posted in my original question. Did I not see something? In addition the document is dated February 21th 2011, long before Xcode4 support was added to MonoTouch.

Comment: The "Application Loader" is still present! Wow, I did not even consider looking for it, thank you! I'll give it a try.

Comment: The new Xamarin document [Publishing to the App Store](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Publishing_to_the_App_Store) is more up-to-date than Building for Distribution.